# Use @NamedEntityGraph on attribute from @MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I tried many different things and did loads of research, yet still fail to get the following working: I want to define an `@NamedEntityGraph` on an entity, but the attribute I refer to is located in the parent class, which is defined with `@MappedSuperclass`.

I have the slight feeling (also after checking the code how the entity graphs are built) that this does not work, but maybe someone can shed some light on it.

Here's in detail what we are trying to to (some things shortened):

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class UserBase {
  private Long id;
  private String loginname;
  private String password;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<Role> roles;
  ....
}
```

And the actual entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(
  name = "withRoles",
  attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode("roles") })
public class User extends UserBase {
   ....
}
```

What happens is, that we get the error

```
Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name [roles] on this ManagedType [some.package.path.User]
```

Stepping through the graph creation code I can see that it only looks at the attributes defined on the class itself, none from the supertype. Any chance I can define the graph in such a way, that this works?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Is your getter `getId()` annotated with something? Can you post that part of code?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `includeAllAttributes=true`:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
  name = "withRoles",
  includeAllAttributes=true
  attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode("roles") })
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't help. Still the same exception :-/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the entityGraphs should be defined in the base class and add them there all the attributes and *subclasses* to be retrieved using the `subclassSubgraphs`

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NamedEntityGraph.html

But... I expected it to work differently by getting the names from the actual subclasses of the annotated class. That way I could go adding nodes in my subclasses.

It looks like it works the other way so you *MUST* make your base class annotations dependent on the children classes details.

BTW!
the otehr guy´s answer seems to be correct almost, you only have to remove the `attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode("roles") })`. And the parents attribs will be in there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you encountered Hibernate bug [HHH-10261 - Creating an entity sub graph on inherited attribute fails](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10261), which was fixed in Hibernate 5.0.8.

Note: The test code that was added in [the PR](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/1143/files) to fix the issue did not include a test of a many-to-many attribute inherited from the superclass, so there is a possibility that you might see this error.